# My implementation of binary search through two lists is exhorbitantly slow

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

For an algorithms class I'm in, we are implementing some algorithms and testing their speed. I chose Python as my language to do this. We are given 2 unsorted lists and a number *x*, and we want to find if there are any elements a in S1 and b in S2 such that *a + b = x*. The way I did it is this:

```
def find_in(s, s2):
    start, end = 0, len(s2)-1
    while end >= start:
        mid = start + (end - start) // 2
        if s2[mid] == s:
            return True
        if s2[mid] > s:
            start = mid +1
        if s2[mid] < s:
            end = mid - 1
    return False

@timing
def binary_search(x, s1 : list, s2 : list) -> bool:
    return any( find_in(x - s, sorted(s2)) for s in s1 )
```

So the function loops through an unsorted list and then looks for the element *x - s* in the sorted list using binary search. For whatever reason, for a list length of 10000 generated using Python random module, it is taking 10 seconds on average, which is longer than the brute force method I tried. Is there some subtly in what I wrote that I am missing? I feel as though this should be O(n log n), faster than O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: I'm far from a Python expert, but I'm assuming that the `sorted(s2)` bit gets re-evaluated for each `s` in the comprehension, meaning that Python has to re-sort the list *n* times. If you pull that out onto the previous line, the function should be much faster.

Comment: Yes, the problem here is that you're sorting the list on every iteration. Python's sorting algorithm is optimised for common cases like sorting a list that is already sorted, but it will still take O(n) time to call `sorted` on the already-sorted list, adding up to O(n^2) since you're sorting O(n) times.

Comment: @kaya3: `sorted` returns a new list rather than mutating the input, so that `sorted` call is performing a full sort from scratch every time.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Oh, right, brainfart from me! So it adds up to O(n^2 log n) then.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Much faster when I don't sort the list every time.

Comment: @ethanmorton You don't even need to sort the elements. Please refer the below soln.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic:

- given a+b = x
- this implies b = x-a (we know x, we know a, we need to find if b exists or not).
- this implies a = x-b (we know x, we know b, we need to find if a exists or not). {this part is not required i guess}

Code:

```
 def AplusB(arr1 , arr2, x):
        #stores the frequency of arr1 (not required i guess)
        d1 = {}
        for i in arr1:
            if(i in d1):
                d1[i] += 1
            else:
                d1[i] = 1
        #stores the frequency of arr2
        d2 = {}
        for i in arr2:
            if(i in d2):
                d2[i] += 1
            else:
                d2[i] = 1
        isAnsExists = False
        for i in arr1:
            val = x - i
            if(val in d2):
                isAnsExists = True
        for i in arr2:
            val = x - i
            if(val in d1):
                isAnsExists = True
        return isAnsExists
```

Random Tests:

```
x = random.randint(0, 10000)
arr1 = [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(100000)]
arr2 = [random.randint(0, 100000) for i in range(100000)]
print( AplusB( arr1,arr2 , x))
```

Comment: Yes, this solution also works, it is actually in a different section of the assignment. For this specific case, I was required to use binary search on a two unsorted lists, as a way to demonstrate the difference between algorithm run times. Using a hashtable or collection or other O(1) data structure was unfortunately prohibited for this section of the assignment.

Comment: ohkkk cool ....